# incremental backup of a single file

Tags: backup, sync

what I want to do is backing up a single text style file in a incremental way. the file is very big (>5gb) and changes daily in a way, that extra information is added to the end of the file. I want to avoid copying 5b+ every day to the backup storage. Is there a way to add only the new parts of my file to the backup?

THX

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` does that by default

from `man rsync`

> rsync [...] is famous for its delta-transfer algorithm, which reduces the amount of data sent over the network by sending only the differences between the source files and the existing files in the destination.

This should work:

```
rsync -av file /path/to/backup/
```

Comment: thanks for that. I was thinking of rsync, too, but it seems that rsync rewrites the whole file again at the destination at each update process instead of "append" to the file. It only sends the deltas, but rewrites the file. my point is slightly different, i want to avoid heavy SSD wear on the backup side.

Comment: Try to add the --inplace option.

Comment: same with --inplace, except that the backup file is overwritten in its original location, saves peak disk usage, but still the file gets written completely new every time...